# Microsoft word - Destination master file

Tags: ms-word

I hope you are well.

I have a word file, called destination file, where I want to have the same information that I add to two other word files (source files).

I know that I can copy the content from both data source files and then paste special as a link into the destination file or create an InsertText field in the destination file to bring the content of bookmarks from the source files.

However, the problem that I have is that if I add new content to the data source files, this content does not get added to the destination file. If I amend the content from the data source files, the content also changes in the destination file but not if I add extra content.

Can you please help? Do I have to write a macro to do so?

Thanks
Sanchez

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word  or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums.

Comment: You should consider using INCLUDETEXT fields, rather than the LINk fields your current approach produces. INCLUDETEXT fields can be used with or without bookmarks and the content can be updated from either the source document or the destination document.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.office-forums.com/threads/create-a-dynamic-master-file.2351555/. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184